# Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Could not parse BigInt

Tags: flutter, dart, numberformatexception, formatexception

I haven't received this error before and I don't remember where I used BigInt, and it didn't specify a file. When I delete the application and run it again, the application opens, but when I run it from time to time while it is open, this error appears and the screen freezes in the splash screen. I have to delete and reinstall it to run it.

I couldn't try anything because I couldn't determine where the problem was.

[GETX] Instance "NetworkManager" has been created
[GETX] Instance "NetworkManager" has been initialized
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Could not parse BigInt

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.